# pyqt6 не может найти QOpenGLFunctions

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyqt6

NameError: name 'QOpenGLFunctions' is not defined

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt6.QtOpenGLWidgets import QOpenGLWidget
from PyQt6.QtOpenGL import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

class CubeOpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget, QOpenGLFunctions):
   

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateRotation)
        self.timer.start(10)
        self.rotation = 0

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.initializeOpenGLFunctions()
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(45, w / h, 0.1, 50.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
        glRotatef(self.rotation, 3, 1, 1)
        self.drawCube()

    def drawCube(self):
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        for edge in edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
        glEnd()

    def updateRotation(self):
        self.rotation += 1
        self.update()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        glWidget = CubeOpenGLWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(glWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    verticies = (
        (1, -1, -1),
        (1, 1, -1),
        (-1, 1, -1),
        (-1, -1, -1),
        (1, -1, 1),
        (1, 1, 1),
        (-1, -1, 1),
        (-1, 1, 1)
    )
    edges = (
        (0, 1),
        (0, 3),
        (0, 4),
        (2, 1),
        (2, 3),
        (2, 7),
        (6, 3),
        (6, 4),
        (6, 7),
        (5, 1),
        (5, 4),
        (5, 7)
    )
    main()
```

Comment: `from PyQt6.QtGui import QOpenGLFunctions` ? 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopen

Comment: @S.Nick 404 - Page Not Found

Comment: @Amgarak sorry   https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglfunctions.html

Comment: @S.Nick  from PyQt6.QtGui import QOpenGLFunctions
ImportError: cannot import name 'QOpenGLFunctions' from 'PyQt6.QtGui'

Comment: CS Flow max,, я не знаю, попробуйте почитать https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt%5D+or+%5Bpyqt4%5D+or+%5Bpyqt5%5D+or+%5Bpyqt6%5D+or+%5Bpyside2%5D+or+%5Bpyside6%5D+QOpenGLFunctions